# Python appending new Lists to JSON file with loop

Tags: python, json, append

I want to update a JSON file in a for loop

In the for loop I have following code:

```
with open('immodata.json', 'a') as file:
    json.dump([{'preis' : priceList, 'plz' : plzList, 'zimmer' : roomList, 'wohnflaeche' : sqrList} for priceList, plzList, roomList, sqrList in zip(priceList, plzList, roomList, sqrList)], file)
```

The problem is this is adding the new Data as sole Data instead of continuing the JSON.

What I get:

```
[{"preis": "1750000", "plz": "5222", "zimmer": "5.5", "wohnflaeche": "185"}][{"preis": "1750000", "plz": "5222", "zimmer": "5.5", "wohnflaeche": "185"}]
```

What I want:

```
[{"preis": "1750000", "plz": "5222", "zimmer": "5.5", "wohnflaeche": "185"}, {"preis": "1650000", "plz": "5222", "zimmer": "5.5", "wohnflaeche": "155"}
```

I assume I have to read out the file, add the new data to the list, and then append to the JSON File, but I did not find out how I would to this.

Comment: assuming you have a json file, I would read in the file contents using `json.load`, then use `+=` to append to the list, then write back the updated data to the file.

Comment: Please show the (initial) lists. Also as a suggestion don't use same names when iterating.

Comment: You can't just add an "addition" to the json file, since you need to at least change the last characters in the source file. Therefore, download the entire file, then change it as you need, and then overwrite the resulting one.

Comment: Thanks to the comments, I solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Alright, thanks to the comments below my question I was able to solve the problem.

```
json_data = []

#GET OLD LIST
if exists('immodata.json'):
    with open ('immodata.json') as json_file:
     json_data = json.load(json_file)
else:
    with open('immodata.json', 'a') as file:
        print("Created new immodata.json File")

#CREATE THE NEW LIST
new_list = [{'preis': priceList, 'plz': plzList, 'zimmer': roomList, 'wohnflaeche': sqrList} for priceList, plzList, roomList, sqrList in zip(priceList, plzList, roomList, sqrList)]

#ADD THE NEW LIST TO THE OLD
json_data += new_list


with open('immodata.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(json_data, file)
```

I downloaded the file, added the new list to the old one and then wrote this to a new one.